# Jadira UserType library JavaTimeZoneWorkaroundHelper

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jodatime

I'm using Joda library for my Date/Time objects and the jadira userType project to persist these stuffs via Hibernate in my MySQL database.

When running the app I get

```
4 mars 2013 18:48:18 org.jadira.usertype.spi.reflectionutils.JavaTimeZoneWorkaroundHelper <clinit>
ATTENTION: Under JDK 6 it may not be possible to handle DST transitions correctly
4 mars 2013 18:48:18 org.jadira.usertype.spi.reflectionutils.JavaTimeZoneWorkaroundHelper <clinit>
GRAVE: Running under a Zone that uses daylight saving time. To avoid incorrect datetimes being stored during DST transition, either update to JDK 7 or use a Timezone for the JDK without Daylight Saving Time
```

So from the text I have two options :
- install JDK 7, which I don't want to do (I'm on a mac OS 10.6.8 and I also don't want to use "too recent" java version)
- Use a timezone without DST. This means I have to set the default TimeZone for my JVM to a location like Russia or somewhere in South America.

- Can I simply disable the `JavaTimeZoneWorkaroundHelper` feature from Jadira ? How ?
- I think of another option : do not use jadira for what it offers (conversion of joda objects to strings and conversion from string to joda objects) and do the converter myself.

What do you suggest ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly set java and database time zones used for mapping independent of the machine your app is running. Generally it is good practice to store date and time in UTC time zone in database. Try if this solves your problem.

```
 @TypeDef(name = "myDateTime", 
          typeClass = org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime.class,
      parameters = {@Parameter(value="UTC", name="databaseZone"), 
                    @Parameter(value="UTC", name="javaZone")})
```

Comment: It's not working. I set the JVM param using -Duser.timezone="GMT" instead

Comment: GMT and UTC are effectively the same, at least close enough for all but scientific time keeping. See the Wikipedia entry: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time

Answer (score 0):

If you add this @TypeDef to the package-info.java file,
and add @Type(name = "myDateTime") to the attribute that should have this type, it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Since this question was created newer versions of the usertype library were created that removed the message. So if you use a recent version like [3.2.0.GA in maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.jadira.usertype%7Cusertype.core%7C3.2.0.GA%7Cjar). It fixes the problem.